# How to get on top-level const pointer using "auto"?

Tags: c++, c++11

In short words:

Per C++ Primer, pg 69, "auto": 
"If we want the deduced type to have a top-level *const*, we must say so explicitly".

I would get an top-level const pointer:

```
int i = 42;
const auto *p = &i;
```

But the resulted p has type `const int *` instead of expected `int * const`. I can even reassign it `p = 0;`. why?
(note: the format of pointer type deduction using `auto *` is from the book.)

Comment: `const int *p = &i;` is not top-level `const`, either. That has nothing to do with `auto`.

Comment: That's not what "top-level" means...

Comment: re "the resulted p has type `int *`", no it doesn't.

Comment: @Alf True. You are right. Fixed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your example, `p` is a pointer to a `const int`, not a `const` pointer to an `int`. The latter can be achieved with the following statement:

```
auto* const p = &i;
```

Answer (score 9):

With `auto`, you don't even need the asterisk, which makes it easy:

```
const auto p = &i;
```

Here, `auto` deduces the type to be `int *`, making it `int * const`. Note that whether it's `const auto` or `auto const` does not make a difference, just as with a `typedef` name.

In your example, only `int` fits as the deduced type, making `p` a `const int *`. This is not a top-level `const`, but a pointer to a `const int`.

See it work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cc860579bb897c8).

Comment: +1 from me, but I suspect the downvote might be because you don't actually answer the question (of why `const auto *` doesn't work), and the rest does look a little bit as if it's a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @hvd, Fair enough. I added some text. The downvote came the instant I posted the answer, too, before the verification link even, so maybe the downvoter just thought it was wrong, or took it to be too comment-like.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your original code,

```
int i = 42;
const auto *p = &i;
```

adding a

```
cout << typeid(p).name() << endl;
```

reports

```
int const *
```

with Visual C++.

Which contradicts your statement

> **”** the resulted p has type `int *`

---

Here's one way to take full control:

```
int i = 42;
auto const *const p = &i;
```

Remove the first `const` if you want a const pointer to mutable object.

---

Alternatively, as noted by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) in his answer, if you want a const pointer to mutable object you can just do

```
auto const p = &i;
```

Answer (score 1):

The type deduction through `auto` works exactly as it does for function templates. So, when you write `const auto *p = &i;`, the type of `p` is exactly the type of `p` in the call to the below template which would match `f(&i)`.

```
template<typename U>
void f(const U* p);
```

Thus, the type is `const int*`. If you want `p` to be `int * const`, the right expression is `auto * const p = &i`.

Answer (score 0):

Position of `const` before/after the pointer declaration(`*`) changes the meaning.

Below example shows a few combination of with `auto`, `const` and `*` - and their interpretation.

```
    int main() {
        auto i = 2;               // int

        const auto a = &i;        // int * const
        // a = &j;                // Error: addr is const
        *a = 4;                   // OK (value is NOT const)

        const auto* b = &i;       // const int *
        // *b = 4;                // Error: value is const
        b = &j;                   // OK (addr is NOT const)

        auto* const c = &i;       // const int *       - (Your case!)
        *c = 4;                   // OK (value is NOT const)
        // c = &j;                // Error: addr is const

        const auto* const d = &i; // const int * const
        // *d = 4;                // Error: Both value & addr are const
        // d = &j;                // Error: Both value & addr are const
    }
```